# Fastest Way to Drop Duplicated Index in a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

If I want to drop duplicated index in a dataframe the following doesn't work for obvious reasons:

```
myDF.drop_duplicates(cols=index)
```

and

```
myDF.drop_duplicates(cols='index')
```

looks for a column named 'index'

If I want to drop an index I have to do:

```
myDF['index'] = myDF.index
myDF= myDF.drop_duplicates(cols='index')
myDF.set_index = myDF['index']
myDF= myDF.drop('index', axis =1)
```

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035764/remove-rows-with-duplicate-indices-pandas-dataframe-and-timeseries

Comment: @PaulH: The answer to your question by Luciano is the same as my question just in a single line

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Simply: `DF.groupby(DF.index).first()`

Comment: @CT Zhu - If I use this method it is combining my tow indes columsn into a single column.I don't want that to happed.Is there a way around it?

Comment: @liv2hak, mind ask a new question with a minimal example dataset?

Comment: @CTZhu - I have figured that out. But can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33792915/pandas-mean-calculation-over-a-column-in-a-csv .thanks

Comment: @CTZhu This transforms the the geopandas data frame to a pandas data frame, which may create problems (it did to me).

Comment: When I was working with a multi-index, the result index did not include any names. The index negation (danielstn, below) did not have this undesired effect.

Answer (score 53):

The 'duplicated' method works for dataframes and for series. Just select on those rows which aren't marked as having a duplicate index:

```
df[~df.index.duplicated()]
```

Comment: This would drop all duplicates though?

Comment: Note that this is the fastest method for the test cases I investigated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035764/remove-rows-with-duplicate-indices-pandas-dataframe-and-timeseries/34297689#34297689 

You can also reproduce the behavior of the accepted answer exactly using: `df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='first)]`

Comment: `keep` defaults to `first` anyway.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `numpy.unique` to obtain the index of unique values and use `iloc` to get those indices:

```
>>> df
        val
A  0.021372
B  1.229482
D -1.571025
D -0.110083
C  0.547076
B -0.824754
A -1.378705
B -0.234095
C -1.559653
B -0.531421

[10 rows x 1 columns]

>>> idx = np.unique(df.index, return_index=True)[1]
>>> df.iloc[idx]
        val
A  0.021372
B  1.229482
C  0.547076
D -1.571025

[4 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: This is MUCH faster.....even faster if you use df.ix[idx]