# Elegant way to sum over duplicate MultiIndex values

Tags: python, pandas, code-readability

I have a DataFrame with a many-levelled MultiIndex.

I know that there are duplicates in the MultiIndex *(because I don't care about a distinction that the underlying databse does care about)*

I want to sum over these duplicates:

```
>>> x = pd.DataFrame({'month':['Sep', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Oct'], 'day':['Mon', 'Mon', 'Mon', 'Tue'], 'sales':[1,2,3,4]})
>>> x
   day month  sales
0  Mon   Sep      1
1  Mon   Sep      2
2  Mon   Oct      3
3  Tue   Oct      4
>>> x = x.set_index(['day', 'month'])
           sales
day month       
Mon Sep        1
    Sep        2
    Oct        3
Tue Oct        4
```

To give me

```
day month       
Mon Sep        3
    Oct        3
Tue Oct        4
```

Buried deep in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13036848/2071807) to a similar question is the suggestion:

```
df.groupby(level=df.index.names).sum()
```

But this seems to me to fail the ['readability counts' criterion](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds) of good Python code.

Does anyone know of a more human-readable way?

Comment: try: ``df.sum(level=[levels_that_I_want])``

Comment: I want all the levels, since I'm really looking for duplicates.

Comment: pls show an example then, as you normally won't have duplicates with a multi-index, so show construction.

Comment: It might make sense to allow something like ``df.sum(level='all')``, which I guess is unambiguous if no levels are named 'all'. what do you think?

Comment: Isn't this a more generic use-case than adding something to `sum`? Might I not also want to take the `max` and `min`? In which case, it might be more like `df.groupby(level='all')`.

Comment: of course, nothing to do with sum specifically (and ``df.sum(level=....)`` actually does a groupby), it has to do with handling ``level='all'`` translating to all levels.

Comment: By the way, a simple way to avoid this duplicates business is to just have another arbitrary level of the index that deduplicates with `0, 1, 2...`

Comment: @Jeff : `all` is an okayish name for a column (and hence for a level). How about something along the lines of `level=[]`? Me personally, I'd prefer inconsistency with `sum()` [maybe make `=all` deprecated after all] over breaking code if users use `all` as a column name (especially since that's not a magic word).

Comment: yeh, using an empty list ``[]`` would prob be better. Pls open an issue for this suggestion if you'd like (with an example)