# Beautiful soup get text for multiple pages

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I try to scrape news pages of a German party and store all information in a dataframe ("python beginner"). There exist only a small problem, when I want to store the whole text or even the date into the dataframe. It seems like that only the last element of the text (p ... /p) will be stored in the row. I think the problem occurs because the iteration over the loop is misleading.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests 
from time import sleep
from random import randint
from time import time
import numpy as np
from urllib.request import urlopen

data = pd.DataFrame()
teaser = ()
title = []
content = ()
childrenUrls = []
mainPage = "https://www.fdp.de"
start_time = time()
counter = 0

#for i in list(map(lambda x: x+1, range(3))):
for i in range(3):

    counter = counter + 1
    sleep(randint(1,3))
    elapsed_time = time() - start_time
    print('Request: {}; Frequency: {} requests/s'.format(counter, counter/elapsed_time))
    url = "https://www.fdp.de/seite/aktuelles?page="+str(i)
    #print(url)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    uls = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'field-title'})

    for ul in uls:
        for li in ul.find_all('h2'):
            for link in li.find_all('a'):
                url = link.get('href')
                contents = link.text
                print(contents)
                childrenUrls = mainPage+url
                print(childrenUrls)

                childrenPages = urllib2.urlopen(childrenUrls)
                soupCP = BeautifulSoup(childrenPages, 'html.parser')

                #content1 = soupCP.findAll('p').get_text()
                #print(content1)

                for content in soupCP.findAll('p'):
                    #for message in content.get('p'):
                    content = content.text.strip()
                    print(content)

                for teaser in soupCP.find_all('div', class_ = 'field-teaser'):
                    teaser = teaser.text.strip()
                    print(date)

                for title in soupCP.find_all('title'):
                    title = title.text.strip()
                    print(ttt)

                df = pd.DataFrame(
                    {'teaser': teaser,
                     'title' : title,
                    'content' : content}, index=[counter])

                data = pd.concat([data, df])
    #join(str(v) for v in value_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to save the text from each loop in a list, and not in a simple string variable. On each iteration, your code redefines the values on the variables; which leads to losing the previous data.

A good approach, is to use [**list comprehension**](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) here. Replace the last 3 `for` loops of your code with this:

```
content = [x.text.strip() for x in soupCP.find_all('p')]
teaser = [x.text.strip() for x in soupCP.find_all('div', class_='field-teaser')]
title = [x.text.strip() for x in soupCP.find_all('title')]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'teaser': teaser,
     'title': title,
     'content': content}, index=[counter])

data = pd.concat([data, df])
```

A simple explanation of *list comprehension*:

The line `content = [x.text.strip() for x in soupCP.find_all('p')]` is equivalent to:

```
content = []
for x in soupCP.find_all('p'):
    content.append(x.text.strip())
```

Comment: Okay, thanks your very much for your help! I replaced my code with your suggestions, but another problem occur, which is maybe related to the index or array of the dataframe. This is the displayed error code: `ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 5), indices imply (3, 1)`

Comment: Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719407/pandas-concat-valueerror-shape-of-passed-values-is-blah-indices-imply-blah2). I think you've to replace `.concat` with `.join`

Comment: If none of the solutions on SO work, I think you should ask a new question. This question was about the problem with `BeautifulSoup` (which is solved), and the new one is about `pandas`. If you want, you can link this question to the other. I don't have much experience with `pandas`, and if you ask a new question specific to the issue, you'll get better answers from others.