# Concating single columns multiple files of different shape

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have 200 files of different which I need to concat column after column into one file. These 200 files are in one directory, and so I tried the following script.

```
path = '/data' 
files = os.listdir(path)

files_txt  = [os.path.join(path,i) for i in files if i.endswith('tsv')]

## Change it into dataframe
dfs = [pd.DataFrame.from_csv(x, sep='\t')[[6]] for x in files_txt]
##Concatenate it
merged = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

But it throws the follwoing value error as the shape is different for each of these files. I would to have some solution.
Thank you

Here is error,

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (149, 13864), indices imply (149, 13860)
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719407/pandas-concat-valueerror-shape-of-passed-values-is-blah-indices-imply-blah2

Comment: No I cannot reset index on a list dfs is list, read as dataframe

Comment: You could try do it after `from_csv`, but not sure it will help. Does the files have the same number of rows or can it differ? If diffferent you can pass `ignore_index=True` to `concat`.

Comment: ignore_index throws the same error message

Comment: why are you using `DataFrame.from_csv`? That API was deprecated years ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index contain the duplicates , then `concat` will failed , since it will base on the index to join the dataframe

```
dfs = [pd.DataFrame.from_csv(x, sep='\t')[[6]].reset_index(drop=True) for x in files_txt]
##Concatenate it
merged = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
```

Using the check

```
for x in dfs : 
    print(x.index.is_unique)
```

In order to reproduced the error

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2]},index=[1,1])
pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
```

> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 5), indices imply (2, 3)

Comment: I need the index

Comment: @user1017373 even it is duplicated ?

Comment: There is no duplicated  index I checked it

Comment: @user1017373 I do not think so .