# Concat gives Shape of passed values is X, indices imply Y

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe (df) my goal is to add a new column ("grad") that corresponds to the [gradient](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) between the points if they have the same index.

First I didn't find an easy way to do it using only pandas for now I use numpy+pandas. I have written a function to get the gradient for each row by group, and it works but it is not pretty and a bit wonky.

Second I want to add the pandas series of numpy arrays to the df but I don't know how to do so. I tried to  stack them so i get a series of size (0,9) (grouped_2 ) but when I use concat I have the following message: "ValueError: Shape of passed values is (48, 3), indices imply (16, 3)". According to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719407/pandas-concat-valueerror-shape-of-passed-values-is-blah-indices-imply-blah2)  I think having duplicate index values is the problem but I can't modify the index of my first df.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], 
                  data={'value': [1,5,8,10,12,1,2,8,2], 'diff_day':[-1,0,2,3,4,-2,-1,0,10]} )
def grad(gr):
        val = gr['value']
        dif = gr['diff_day']
        return np.gradient(val, dif)


grouped_1 = df.groupby(level=0).apply(grad)
grouped_2 = pd.DataFrame(grouped_1.values.tolist(), index=grouped_1.index).stack().reset_index(drop=True)
result = pd.concat([df, grouped_2], axis=1)
```

My expectation was the following dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(index = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], 
                      data={'value': [1,5,8,10,12,1,2,8,2], 'diff_day':[-1,0,2,3,4,-2,-1,0,10], 'grad':[4,3.16,1.83,2,2,1,3.5,5.4,-0.6]} )
```

Comment: Hi @JulienAzhar , could you add the expected behavior / output to your example? It's a bit hard to follow you otherwise.

Comment: @ibarrond done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple way:

```
df['grad'] = np.gradient(df['value'], df['diff_day'])
```

To make your solution work, you can do:

```
result = pd.concat([df.reset_index(drop=True), grouped_2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
```

Comment: The second solution works fine, thanks. The first doesn't work because I have two groups, hence the groupby.