# Python Pandas: Shape of passed values is (126, 5), indices imply (84, 5)

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes with 84 rows, clearly the same lengths, but when i want to concat them to 1 df (concat by column - to have the name, Edge and Offset to the right of Latitude and Longitude), i get this error,.

what is going on?

```
     Latitude  Longitude
0   45.403538 -75.735729
1   45.403506 -75.735699
2   45.409095 -75.722588
3   45.409069 -75.722552
4   45.413496 -75.714184
..        ...        ...
79  45.415609 -75.644769
80  45.416073 -75.645726
81  45.416193 -75.638802
82  45.416172 -75.638223

[84 rows x 2 columns]

  name Edge  Offset
0    TUN-W    1    3000
1    TUN-E    2    3000
2    BAY-W    5  102510
3    BAY-E    6  102579
4    PIM-W    5  186035
..     ...  ...     ...
37  PTSTTW   33   52710
38  PTSTTE   34   18997
39   PAG11   40   24362
40   PAG14   50    9927
41  PHND15  177   11662

[84 rows x 3 columns]
```

This is my code liner

```
output_df = pd.concat( [output_df, input_df], axis=1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas concat: ValueError: Shape of passed values is blah, indices imply blah2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719407/pandas-concat-valueerror-shape-of-passed-values-is-blah-indices-imply-blah2)

Comment: Is `output_df = pd.concat( [output_df.reset_index(drop=True), input_df.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)` acceptable?

Comment: yea i alr did all my research on other stack posts but those egs r really complicated. i just needed smth simple coz i know myself that my component dfs can be printed out. so it shld not have been that complicated

Answer (score 1):

I got it:

```
 name Edge  Offset
0    TUN-W    1    3000
1    TUN-E    2    3000
2    BAY-W    5  102510
3    BAY-E    6  102579
4    PIM-W    5  186035
..     ...  ...     ...
37  PTSTTW   33   52710
38  PTSTTE   34   18997
39   PAG11   40   24362
40   PAG14   50    9927
41  PHND15  177   11662
```

The indexing was messed up. Somewhere in the middle, the index resets to `0` instead of counting up to `84`.

So i did a `segments_df = segments_df_start.append(segments_df_end).reset_index()` (was in earlier part of my code) to fix the indexing for that dataframe before I pass it over.

So ALWAYS remember to check your indexes and **`.reset_index()`** , when troubleshooting!!