# how could i delete rows with repeating/duplicate index from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
>>> df
zeroa  zerob zeroc zerod zeroe zero
FSi                                     
1       10    100     a    ok   NaN   ok
1       11    110        temp   NaN  NaN
2       12    120     c  temp   NaN  NaN
3      NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN    ok  NaN
```

I want to keep only unique indexes, as index 1 is repeating I want its second instance to be dropped, how could I do that ? I want my result as

```
>>> df
     zeroa  zerob zeroc zerod zeroe zero
FSi                                     
1       10    100     a    ok   NaN   ok
2       12    120     c  temp   NaN  NaN
3      NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN    ok  NaN
```

Comment: While this question is a duplicate, the accepted answer is not the best answer IMO, so here is a link to the [best answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34297689/5276797).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without resetting the index:

```
df[~df.index.duplicated()]
```

Comment: nice, I like your solution more then mine :)

Comment: I tried the `reset_index` route first, but Google saved me ;)

Comment: thanks it worked !!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok something like this should help:

```
df = df.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='FSi', keep='first').set_index('FSi')
```

Explanation:  First we reset_index which creates a column **FSi** cause drop_duplicates works on columns and not on index. We keep the first one and set_index again back to **FSi**