# Pandas dataframe: keep rows with duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, duplicates

This question is slightly more complicated than [Remove duplicate rows in pandas dataframe based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43814487/remove-duplicate-rows-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-condition):

Instead of one 'valu' column, I now have two columns 'valu1', 'valu2':

```
         t    valu1    valu2
2015-08-01        1       10
2015-08-01        2       11
2015-08-01        3       12
2015-09-31        4       15
2015-10-31        5       13
```

In the dataframe above, I want to remove the duplicate rows (i.e. row where the column `'t'` is repeated) by retaining the row with a higher value in the `valu1` column and a lower value in the `value2` column.

Expected outcome:

```
         t    valu1    valu2
2015-08-01        3       10
2015-09-31        4       15
2015-10-31        5       13
```

The `df.sort_values()` and `drop_duplicates` with `keep='last'` mentioned in the linked question obviously don't work.

Something I can think of now is:

```py
#Let's call the dataframe df
dups = df[df['t'].duplicated()]['t'].drop_duplicates()  #get duplicated dates
for d in dups:
    max_v1 = df[df['t'] == d]['valu1'].max()  #find the max of valu1 on day d
    min_v2 = df[df['t'] == d]['valu2'].min()  #find the min of valu2 on day d
    df[df['t'] == d]['valu1'] = max_v1        #set valu1 of day d to max_v1
    df[df['t'] == d]['valu2'] = min_v2        #set valu2 of day d to min_v2

df = df[~df.index.duplicated()]               #drop everything duplicated
```

I think this should work, but it really seems unsophisticated, especially I actually need to do this for a large dataset. Any idea of how I should approach this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
df.groupby('t').agg({'valu1':'max','valu2':'min'}).reset_index()
            t  valu1  valu2
0  2015-08-01      3     10
1  2015-09-31      4     15
2  2015-10-31      5     13
```