# Python: drop duplicated index in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the date as below and the Date as Index. I want to remove the duplicated Date

```
           Stock      Open      High       Low     Close Adj Close  Volume
Date                                                                      
2016-05-13   AAD  5.230000  5.260000  5.200000  5.260000  5.260000    5000
2016-05-16   AAD  5.220000  5.260000  5.220000  5.260000  5.260000    6000
2016-05-17   AAD  5.210000  5.260000  5.210000  5.260000  5.260000    2000
2016-05-17   AAD  5.210000  5.260000  5.210000  5.260000  5.260000    2000
2016-05-18   AAD  5.200000  5.250000  5.200000  5.250000  5.250000    3000
```

The output I needed

```
           Stock      Open      High       Low     Close Adj Close  Volume
Date                                                                      
2016-05-13   AAD  5.230000  5.260000  5.200000  5.260000  5.260000    5000
2016-05-16   AAD  5.220000  5.260000  5.220000  5.260000  5.260000    6000
2016-05-17   AAD  5.210000  5.260000  5.210000  5.260000  5.260000    2000
2016-05-18   AAD  5.200000  5.250000  5.200000  5.250000  5.250000    3000
```

I try by using `df.drop_duplicates()` and the output delete extra lines after the duplicated date.

```
          Stock      Open      High       Low     Close Adj Close  Volume
Date                                                                      
2016-05-13   AAD  5.230000  5.260000  5.200000  5.260000  5.260000    5000
2016-05-16   AAD  5.220000  5.260000  5.220000  5.260000  5.260000    6000
2016-05-17   AAD  5.210000  5.260000  5.210000  5.260000  5.260000    2000
```

Comment: I think you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34297689/2901002)

Comment: @jezrael I try but not working with duplicated. It just eliminate the index, I want to drop a row as shown above

Comment: It use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) - so it should works `df = df3[~df3.index.duplicated()]`

Comment: @jezrael what is ~df3 means?

Comment: ~ is a 'not' operator.  Where d3.index is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use the information Jezrael provided.

Input Dataframe:

```
print(df)
           Stock  Open  High   Low  Close  Adj Close  Volume
2016-05-13   AAD  5.23  5.26  5.20   5.26       5.26    5000
2016-05-16   AAD  5.22  5.26  5.22   5.26       5.26    6000
2016-05-17   AAD  5.21  5.26  5.21   5.26       5.26    2000
2016-05-17   AAD  5.21  5.26  5.21   5.26       5.26    2000
2016-05-18   AAD  5.20  5.25  5.20   5.25       5.25    3000

df1 = df[~df.index.duplicated(keep='last')]
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
           Stock  Open  High   Low  Close  Adj Close  Volume
2016-05-13   AAD  5.23  5.26  5.20   5.26       5.26    5000
2016-05-16   AAD  5.22  5.26  5.22   5.26       5.26    6000
2016-05-17   AAD  5.21  5.26  5.21   5.26       5.26    2000
2016-05-18   AAD  5.20  5.25  5.20   5.25       5.25    3000
```