# Faster way to remove duplicated indices from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates, pandas-groupby

What is a efficient way to remove duplicated rows from a pandas dataframe
where I would like always to *keep the first value that is not NAN*.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [np.nan,np.nan,2,2,3,3,5],
                     'b': [2,1,1,1,np.nan,2,1]},
                     index=[pd.Timestamp('2018-03-01'), pd.Timestamp('2018-03-02'),
                            pd.Timestamp('2018-03-02'), pd.Timestamp('2018-03-02'),
                            pd.Timestamp('2018-03-03'), pd.Timestamp('2018-03-03'),
                            pd.Timestamp('2018-03-04')])

print(data)
>              a    b
> 2018-03-01  NaN  2.0
> 2018-03-02  NaN  1.0  # take 'a' from next row, 'b' from this row
> 2018-03-02  2.0  1.0
> 2018-03-02  2.0  1.0
> 2018-03-03  3.0  NaN  # take 'a' from this row but 'b' from next row
> 2018-03-03  3.0  2.0
> 2018-03-04  5.0  1.0

# Is there something faster?
x = data.groupby(data.index).first()
print(x)
```

Should give:

```
>               a    b
> 2018-03-01  NaN  2.0
> 2018-03-02  2.0  1.0
> 2018-03-03  3.0  2.0
> 2018-03-04  5.0  1.0
```

`data.groupby(data.index).first()` does that job but it is ridiculously slow.
For a dataframe of shape `(5'730'238, 7)` it required 40 minutes to remove the duplicates,
for another table of shape `(1'191'704, 339)` it took **5 hours 20 minutes**.
(datetime index, all columns integer/float).
Note that the data might contain only few duplicated values.

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34297689/5362339) , they suggest to use `data[~data.index.duplicated(keep='first')]`,
but this does not handle NANs in the desired way.

It doesn't really matter, if I choose `first`, `last`, `mean` or whatever, as long as
it is fast.

Is there a faster way than `groupby` or is there a problem with my data that's making it slow.

Comment: I think this is going to be excessively challenging without the groupby.

Comment: Is the date index in ascending order?

Comment: How do you have millions of records with daily index? Or daily is just sample data and in reality is has another frequency?

Comment: The index is a-priory not sorted but I wouldn't mind to sort it. This is just a sample, I think the real data is pulled together from different loggers, each of them has 1s to 10s intervals.

Comment: @coldspeed is there a known limitation of groupby where it takes longer on bad data (e.g. too many columns, not sorted index, ...)? 5 hours seems really ridiculous :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is not in algorithm of `groupby` but in memory consumption. For million records with seven float columns it took 300 ms, you can speedup twice by using resample with your frequency. But 2 million records with 400 float columns is 7Gb of memory and it becomes  hell of swapping memory to disk with. On my 16Gb of physical memory and SSD HDD it took 3 minutes to perform `groupby` on that sample size (with sorted index) most of the time was used to swap memory to disk.

I suggest to: sort your data then split and process it in batches. If you can split it before sorting do it before.

---

**1. Sort**

It will sort it as in your sample

```py
df_sample.reset_index(inplace=True)
df_sample.sort_values(by=df_sample.columns.tolist(),na_position ='first',inplace=True)
df_sample.set_index('date',inplace=True)
```

**2. Work in batches**

This is not a safe splitting method but enough for performance testing

```py
step = 20000
print (df_sample.shape)
%timeit x = pd.concat([df_sample[s:s+step].resample('min').first() for s in range(0,df_sample.shape[0],step)],axis=0)
```

It took two minutes instead of three without splitting.

---