# Drop duplicate times in xarray

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray

I'm reading NetCDF files with `open_mfdataset`, which contain duplicate times. For each duplicate time I only want to keep the first occurrence, and drop the second (it will never occur more often). The problem is quite similar to [this Pandas question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035764/remove-rows-with-duplicate-indices-pandas-dataframe-and-timeseries), but none of the solutions provided there seem to work with Xarray.

To reproduce the problem:

```
import numpy as np
import netCDF4 as nc4
import xarray as xr

# Create example NetCDF files
for t in range(2):
    nc    = nc4.Dataset('test{}.nc'.format(t), 'w')
    dim_t = nc.createDimension('time', None)
    var_t = nc.createVariable('time', 'f8', ('time',))
    var_s = nc.createVariable('var', 'f8', ('time',))
    var_t.setncattr('units', 'hours since 2001-01-01 00:00:00')
    var_t[:] = t*5+np.arange(6)
    var_s[:] = t*5+np.arange(6)+t
    nc.close()

# Read with xarray
f = xr.open_mfdataset(['test0.nc', 'test1.nc'])
```

The times in the resulting `dataset` are:

```
array(['2001-01-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2001-01-01T01:00:00.000000000',
       '2001-01-01T02:00:00.000000000', '2001-01-01T03:00:00.000000000',
       '2001-01-01T04:00:00.000000000', '2001-01-01T05:00:00.000000000',
       '2001-01-01T05:00:00.000000000', '2001-01-01T06:00:00.000000000',
       '2001-01-01T07:00:00.000000000', '2001-01-01T08:00:00.000000000',
       '2001-01-01T09:00:00.000000000', '2001-01-01T10:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Is there an easy way to remove the second ocurance of `2001-01-01T05:00:00.000000000`? The real-life problem deals with multi-dimensional NetCDF files, so switching to Pandas is no option.

***[update]*** The closest I get is following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13036848/3581217); that works for my simple example as long as Dask is not used, if the files contain Dask arrays I get the error:

> 'last' with skipna=True is not yet implemented on dask arrays

But I don't see where I can/have to set `skipna`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think xarray does not have its own method for this purpose, but the following works,

```
In [7]: _, index = np.unique(f['time'], return_index=True)

In [8]: index
Out[8]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])

In [9]: f.isel(time=index)
Out[9]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (time: 11)
Coordinates:
  * time     (time) datetime64[ns] 2001-01-01 2001-01-01T01:00:00 ...
Data variables:
   var      (time) float64 dask.array<shape=(11,), chunksize=(6,)>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this solution. I had exactly the same problem as @bart above with duplicate time entries with `xr.open_mfdataset` and this solution solved it perfectly.

Answer (score 11):

Apparently stackoverflow won't let me comment... I wanted to add to Keisuke's answer. You can also use the `get_index()` function to get a pandas index.

```
f.sel(time=~f.get_index("time").duplicated())
```

Comment: Does not work. Returns `pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects`.

Comment: Works fine for me, but what does '~' do here ?

Comment: The `~` is the invert operator in numpy (and xarray) (https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.invert.html). If used on a boolean array, such as the one that is returned by duplicated function, it is shorthand for a `not` operation. You could also use `np.logical_not` instead of `~` if you wish. You cannot use `~`  as a replacement for np.logical_not for any other type of array, so be careful ;-)