# InvalidIndexError dask dataframe

Tags: pandas, dask

I'm learning dask, and getting this error here and there:

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

There is a preprocessed dask df and I did and can do a lot of operations with it, but a few simple ones throw this error.

I tried resetting index, but it didn't seem, to help.

Question: is there a high lvl answer to what might be wrong? Anywhere I can read about it? Why does it usually happens? Googling didn't help.

For example here is a weird example:
I test df stats after each operation to maybe see anything suspicious.

```
df = load_data()
df.shape[0].compute(), df.npartitions
#ok

df = prepare_target(df)
df.shape[0].compute(), df.npartitions
#ok

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = dask_tts(df.drop('target', 1), df['target'], random_state=1)
#ok

x_train['target'] = y_train
x_test['target'] = y_test
#ok

x_train.shape[0].compute(), x_train.npartitions
x_test.shape[0].compute(), x_test.npartitions
#ok

x_train.index.nunique().compute()
x_test.index.nunique().compute()
#ok

train, smooth_dict = smoothed_likelyhood(x_train) # returns df and dict
train.shape[0].compute()
#ok

test, _ = smoothed_likelyhood(x_test)
test.shape[0].compute()
#ok

train.index.nunique().compute()
#ok
test.index.nunique().compute() # after this line - error
# InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

to point out, only test throws an error

Here I tried to reproduce it, but it works as it should:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask_ml.model_selection import train_test_split

def smoothed_likelyhood(df, alpha=1): # works with dask df
    global_mean = df['target'].mean()
    smooth_dict = {}

    final_df = df.copy()

    for c in [c for c in df.columns if c!='target']:
        n_rows = df[c].value_counts()
        all_means = df.groupby(by=c)['target'].mean()
        temp_result = ((all_means * n_rows + global_mean + alpha) / (n_rows + alpha))    
        final_df[c] = df[c].map(temp_result)
        smooth_dict[c] = temp_result.compute().to_dict()
        
    return final_df, smooth_dict

# TOY EXAMPLE
test = pd.DataFrame({'a':['mos', 'mos', 'london', 'dubai', 'ny', 'mos', 'london', 'dubai', 'shanghai', 'dubai', 'mos', 'london', 'dubai', 'dubai'],
                     'b':['big', 'big', 'big', 'med', 'med', 'med', 'small', 'small', 'small', 'small', 'big', 'med', 'small', 'med'],
                     'target':[1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]}) 

df = dd.from_pandas(test, npartitions=2)
# -----------------------------------------------

print(f'npartitions: {df.npartitions}')
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.drop('target', 1), df['target'], test_size=0.3, shuffle=True)

x_train['target'] = y_train
x_test['target'] = y_test

print(x_train.shape[0].compute(), x_train.index.nunique().compute())
print(x_test.shape[0].compute(), x_test.index.nunique().compute())

train, smooth_dict = smoothed_likelyhood(x_train)
test, _ = smoothed_likelyhood(x_test)

print(train.shape[0].compute(), train.index.nunique().compute())
print(test.shape[0].compute(), test.index.nunique().compute())

# train.compute()

print(train['target'].mean().compute())
print(test['target'].mean().compute())
```

This part worked but when I try doing the same with real data:

```
%%time
df = load_data(stage='prep_2', frac=config.FRAC, verbose=False) # loading many parquet files
df = prepare_target(df) # some small changes to df
# -----------------------------------------------

print(f'npartitions: {df.npartitions}')
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df.drop('target', 1), df['target'], random_state=1)

x_train['target'] = y_train
x_test['target'] = y_test

print(x_train.shape[0].compute(), x_train.index.nunique().compute())
print(x_test.shape[0].compute(), x_test.index.nunique().compute())

train, smooth_dict = smoothed_likelyhood(x_train)
test, _ = smoothed_likelyhood(x_test)

print(x_train.shape[0].compute(), x_train.index.nunique().compute())
print(x_test.shape[0].compute(), x_test.index.nunique().compute())
```

These are the results of prints:

```
npartitions: 10
1476758 164300
164018 106750
1476758 164300
164018 106750
```

and any of these 2 will throw the index error mentioned above:

```
train['target'].mean().compute()
test['target'].mean().compute()
```

If you have any ideas, I might have a look further to investigate, only if I knew where to look.

Thanks.

Comment: it seems like you have index values which are duplicates. Could you post your data here? You might want to try somethign proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64749574/13592469 :  Dask does not have the get index method as far as i know, but you could probably use test.index.compute() to get it as pd index. If you post example code so I can test it, I can give you a more specific answer

Comment: Hi. Please have a look, I edited the question.
ps. test.index.compute() throws same index error

Comment: Thank you for updating, I still cannot run your code because I dont have all the funtions you use (NameError: name 'train_test_split' is not defined). But I will try to help you as good as I can. The error clearly indicates that there are duplicates in the index. What is the output of train['target'].head() with your real data? 
Or if you run:
train['target'] = train['target'].reset_index()
??

Comment: Thanks for sticking around. 
- train['target'].head() - returns as normal, 0 and 1
- train['target'] = train['target'].reset_index() - returns error:
- TypeError: Column assignment doesn't support type dask.dataframe.core.DataFrame

I also added a few imports for you to run. TOY example should be ok now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in smoothed_likelyhood function at:

```
final_df[c] = df[c].map(temp_result)
smooth_dict[c] = temp_result.compute().to_dict()
```

something to do with dask series - temp_result

Usually, with pandas, if I want to replace some values (map them) with some other values in df, I would go like this:

```
dict = {'a':{'a1':1, 'a2':2...}, 'b':{'b1':1, 'b2':2...}}
for c in df.columns: # df.columns = ['a', 'b', ...]
    df[c] = df[c].map(dict[c].get) # swap it inplace
```

it is super fast

but here, in dask, I couldn't turn temp_result to dict (only after computing). And I tried a few things and, surprisingly, simple `df.map(series)` worked. As in mapping series not dict. Ok, but that introduced super sneaky problem with invalid index.

The solution was to use calculated dict (smooth_dict) as with pandas, instead of series (temp_result) and map with it. I think it is suboptimal to calculate something too soon in dask, but I need the results anyway and afaik it is only calculated once here when I call it.

Here is a working function:

```
def smoothed_likelyhood(df, alpha=1):
    """
    Discription:
        preprocess based on mean values of positive events in each category
    Args:
        df: [df] - df to encode
        alpha: [int/float] - regularization param. We can find it with CV
    Returns:
        encoded df, dict to encode user during prediction
    """
    
    global_mean = df['target'].mean()
    smooth_dict = {}

    for c in [c for c in df.columns if c!='target']:
        n_rows = df[c].value_counts()
        all_means = df.groupby(by=c)['target'].mean()
        temp_result = ((all_means * n_rows + global_mean + alpha) / (n_rows + alpha))
        smooth_dict[c] = temp_result.compute().to_dict()
        df[c] = df[c].map(smooth_dict[c])
        
    return df, smooth_dict
```

Still, it takes 25min to chew through 800k * 90 dataframe, which is only 5% of my data. If anyone can suggest how to speed this func in dask, it would be much appreciated.