# Convenient way to deal with ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, concatenation

I am able to search suggestions that show the 'cause' of this error message, but not how to address it -

I encounter this problem every time I try to add a new column to a pandas dataframe by concatenating string values in 2 existing columns.

For instance:

```
wind['timestamp'] = wind['DATE (MM/DD/YYYY)'] + ' ' + temp['stamp']
```

It works if the first item and the second merged with ' ' are each separate dataframe/series.

These attempts are to have date & time merged into the same column so that they get recognized as datetime stamps by pandas library.

I am not certain if I am wrongly using the command or if it is the pandas library features are internally limited, as it keeps returning the `duplicate axis` error msg. I understand the latter is highly unlikely hahaha ...

Could I hear some quick and easy solution out of this?

I mean, I thought sum/subtract and all these operations between column values in a dataframe would be quite easy. Shouldn't be too hard to have it visible on the table either right?

Comment: I strongly suggest checking this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34297689/489364

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Operations between series require non-duplicated indices, otherwise Pandas doesn't know how to align values in calculations. This isn't the case with your data currently.

If you are certain that your series are aligned *by position*, you can call `reset_index` on each dataframe:

```
wind = pd.DataFrame({'DATE (MM/DD/YYYY)': ['2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01']})
temp = pd.DataFrame({'stamp': ['1', '2', '3']}, index=[0, 1, 1])

# ATTEMPT 1: FAIL
wind['timestamp'] = wind['DATE (MM/DD/YYYY)'] + ' ' + temp['stamp']
# ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

# ATTEMPT 2: SUCCESS
wind = wind.reset_index(drop=True)
temp = temp.reset_index(drop=True)
wind['timestamp'] = wind['DATE (MM/DD/YYYY)'] + ' ' + temp['stamp']

print(wind)

  DATE (MM/DD/YYYY)     timestamp
0        2018-01-01  2018-01-01 1
1        2018-02-01  2018-02-01 2
2        2018-03-01  2018-03-01 3
```

Comment: oh man you are awesome. I realize I didnt `reset_index` the temp series. better check the last file too. thx!