# Combining a list of Dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, indexing, concatenation

I have a folder with several .csv-files. Each contains data on *Time, High, Low, Open, Volumefrom, Volumeto, Close* of a cryptocurrency.

I managed to load the .csvs into a list of dataframes and drop the columns *Open, High, Low, Volumefrom, Volumeto* , which I don't need, leaving me with *Time* and *Close* for each dataframe.

Now i want to combine the list of dataframes into one dataframe, where the index starts with the Timestamp of the youngest coin which would be *iota* in this example.

[image: Currency Data Frames]

This is the code I wrote so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

# Path to my folder
PATH_COINS = r"C:\Users\...\Coins"

# creating a path for each of the .csv-files and saving it into a list
namelist = [name for name in os.listdir(PATH_COINS)]
path_lists = [os.path.join(PATH_COINS, path) for path in namelist]

# creating the dataframes and saving them into a list
dfs = [pd.read_csv(k, index_col=0) for k in path_lists]

# dropping unwanted columns 
for num, i in enumerate(dfs):
    i.drop(columns=["Open", "High", "Low", "Volumefrom", "Volumeto"], inplace=True)

# combining the list of dataframes into one dataframe     
pd.concat(dfs, join="inner", axis=1)
```

However i am getting an Errormessage and cant figure out how to achieve my goal:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/Jonas/PycharmProjects/Pandas/main.py", line 16, in 
>       pd.concat(dfs, join="inner", axis=1)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Jonas\PycharmProjects\Pandas\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py",
>   line 226, in concat
>       return op.get_result()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Jonas\PycharmProjects\Pandas\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py",
>   line 423, in get_result
>       copy=self.copy)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Jonas\PycharmProjects\Pandas\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py",
>   line 5425, in concatenate_block_managers
>       return BlockManager(blocks, axes)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Jonas\PycharmProjects\Pandas\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py",
>   line 3282, in **init**
>       self._verify_integrity()
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Jonas\PycharmProjects\Pandas\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py",
>   line 3493, in _verify_integrity
>       construction_error(tot_items, block.shape[1:], self.axes)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\Jonas\PycharmProjects\Pandas\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py",
>   line 4843, in construction_error
>       passed, implied))
>
> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (5, 8514), indices imply (5,
>   8490)

Comment: You probably have duplicate index values in at least one of the DataFrames. If you see any `False` values in the output of `[df.index.is_unique for df in dfs]`, that is likely the source of this error.

Comment: yes, i had duplicates in my .csv files. I didnt even think of that, because i got the data from an api and was expecting it to be cleaned. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

`join` should work

Check for duplicate index values as it doesn't know how to map multiple duplicate indexes across multiple DFs (e.g. `df.index.is_unique`)

Removing duplicate index values (e.g., `df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)`) or one of the methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34297689/7163376) should resolve it.

Comment: thanks for your  answer, i had duplicates in my .csvs, which caused the error.