# Insert ... ON DUPLICATE KEY INSERT something new

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am working on a pandas dataframe and with sqlalchemy . What I am trying to do is to merge multiple identical databases into one. The problem is that the tables may have duplicates between DBs.
Another problem is that I have something around 30M rows and this causes time loss when working around the dataframe (even with chunksize).

I tried to iterate all over the dataframe but that's way too long for checking duplicates. So I wanted to use the SQL query `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY ... do something` but the only possibilities are `UPDATE` and `IGNORE`. What I am trying is to :
 ->insert every rows -> on duplicate key -> update the row I tried to insert and insert it with new id

I couldn't find anything with sqlalchemy for this problem on google

What i'm doing:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
#put all datas in the df for one tables but from all databases

engine = create_engine("mysql://xxx:xxx@localhost/{db}".format(db=dbname))

df.to_sql(con=engine, name=tableName, if_exists='append', chunksize=chunksize, index= False)
```

And the MYSQL error is DUPLICATE VALUE FOR PRIMARY KEY

EDIT: Adding the table schema

```
table1 = Table('table1', metadata,
    Column('id', VARCHAR(40), primary_key=True,nullable=False),
    mysql_engine='InnoDB'
    )

table2= Table('table2', metadata,
    Column('id', VARCHAR(40), primary_key=True,nullable=False),
    Column('id_of', VARCHAR(20),ForeignKey("table1.id"), nullable=False, index= True)
    )

table3= Table('table3', metadata,
    Column('index',BIGINT(10), primary_key=True,nullable=False,autoincrement=True),
    Column('id', VARCHAR(40),nullable=False),
    Column('id_produit', VARCHAR(40),ForeignKey("table2.id"), nullable=False, index= True),
    Column('id_produit_enfant', VARCHAR(40),ForeignKey("table2.id"), nullable=False, index= True)
    )

table4= Table('table4', metadata,
    Column('index',BIGINT(10), primary_key=True,nullable=False,autoincrement=True),
    Column('id', VARCHAR(40),nullable=False),
    Column('id_produit', VARCHAR(40),ForeignKey("table2.id"), nullable=False, index= True)
    )

table5= Table('table5', metadata,
    Column('index',BIGINT(10), primary_key=True,nullable=False,autoincrement=True),
    Column('id', VARCHAR(40),nullable=False),
    Column('id_produit', VARCHAR(40),ForeignKey("table2.id"), nullable=False, index= True)
    )

table6= Table('table6', metadata,
    Column('index',BIGINT(10), primary_key=True,nullable=False,autoincrement=True),
    Column('id', VARCHAR(40),nullable=False),
    Column('id_produit', VARCHAR(40),ForeignKey("table2.id"), nullable=False, index= True)
    )
```

Comment: When you do an INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY .. UPDATE, it does what you say you need, inserts every row and if finds a duplicate key, updates the values you need

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/ This does not say the same as you

Comment: That tutorial says exactly the same as i say. Maybe you didn't understand it. The system tries to insert a row. If it does not exist as a primary key, inserts the row and continues. If the primary key exists, updates the columns you specify after the UPDATE and then continues. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: `If you specify an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause and a row to be inserted would cause a duplicate value in a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, an UPDATE of the old row occurs.` That is the first line of your link. I don't want to update the old row but to add a new one with a modified key

Comment: That ´ s not what you said in your question. You talked about updating the row, no updating the primary key and insert it as a new row

Comment: Yeah i updated the question so that is clearer, imeant update the row I was actually inserting sorry was confusing

Comment: What you can do is iterate over the dataframe and use normal INSERT (inside a Try, Except). If you get a duplicate it will go to the except, there you can change the id and try to do a new INSERT

Comment: I used dataframe because i wanted to avoid inserting rows 1by1 using chunksize

Comment: Do you think it is possible to update the `INSERT INTO tablename id values(123) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE values(123) = values(1234) ` ?

Comment: Yes, you can update the PRIMARY KEY by doing INSERT INTO tablename set id=123 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id=1234. But that will delete the original row and insert a new row with the new id (you won't have two rows, one with id 123 and another one with id 1234, you will only have one row with id 1234)

Comment: And you know if something exists in SQL to do something like that ?

Comment: I think there is nothing to solve it. The only way to do it is what a told you before, iterating over the dataframe and doing an INSERT. If you get a duplicate you modify your id (in python) and try again

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is:

```
DUPLICATE VALUE FOR PRIMARY KEY
```

This is the index in pandas. Panda allows duplicates, for the index and MySQL and other relational databases do not allow that.

> A primary key is a special relational database table column (or combination of columns) designated to uniquely identify all table records. A primary key's main features are: It must contain a unique value for each row of data.

So your problem is how to eliminate [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035764/remove-rows-with-duplicate-indices-pandas-dataframe-and-timeseries) on pandas index.

Comment: That's what i tried to do but because the dataframe is very big, it takes too long to iterate all over

Comment: I believe, just keep on rolling. You are getting there @Hanggy. It takes time :)

Comment: Yeah but i need to make it as shorter as possible

Comment: Then you can drop the primary key restriction in MySQL and you will have it.

Comment: These keys make the database faster, but if you just need to put the data in, and leater you will decide on MySQL end what to do, you are good.

Comment: I would like to do that but it also a foreign key on multiple tables so i have to make it unique for the FK constraint :'(

Comment: I can add the table schema to the question if you want

Comment: sure add it pls