# Python Dataframe - Removing Duplicate Values?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a program that runs completely through but unfortunately is returning duplicates because of the way the base data is structured. Results looks like this:

```
   Date      Amount   Source   Type
  7/16/2019  10        A       B
  7/17/2019  10        A       B
  7/15/2019  10        A       B
  7/15/2019  10        B       B

I'd like to return:
   Date      Amount   Source   Type
  7/17/2019   10        A       B
  7/15/2019   10        B       B
```

7/17/2019 is chosen because its the last date we received 10 from source A and Type B.

I've tried:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='a','b','date', keep="last")
```

but its not quite working. Is there a better way to do this?

**This worked**

```
df[df.Date.eq(df.groupby(['Source','Type'])['Date'].transform('max'))]
```

Comment: `df[df.Date.eq(df.groupby(['Source','Type'])['Date'].transform('max'))]`

Comment: Both throw this error which I haven't dealt with all that much: valueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: @user2679225 df[df.Date.eq(df.groupby(['Source','Type'])['Date'].transform('max').values)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035764/remove-rows-with-duplicate-indices-pandas-dataframe-and-timeseries):

```
non_duplicate_index = ~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')
result = df.loc[non_duplicate_index]
```

`df.index.duplicated(keep='first')` Returns an index containing True/False values. True if the value is duplicated, and False otherwise. Then, `~df.index.duplicated(keep='first')` returns True where the value is not duplicated.

Finally `df.loc[non_duplicate_index]` is an slicing pandas method which returns the df rows where `non_duplicate_index` is True.

Answer (score 1):

`drop_duplicates` will work as well

```
df.sort_values('Date').drop_duplicates(subset=['Source','Type'], keep="last") 
Out[566]: 
        Date  Amount Source Type
3 2019-07-15      10      B    B
1 2019-07-17      10      A    B
```