# Calculating column values for a Dataframe by looking up on another dataframe- Very slow with for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes, let's call them Train and LogItem. There is a column called user_id in both of them.

For each row in Train, I pick the user_id and a date field and then pass it to a function which returns some values by calculating it from the LogItem dataframe which I use to populate  column in Train(LogEntries_7days,Sessioncounts_7days) against the location of that particular row.

```
def ServerLogData(user_id,threshold,threshold7,dataframe):
  dataframe = LogItem[LogItem['user_id']==user_id]
  UserData = dataframe.loc[(dataframe['user_id']==user_id) & 
  (dataframe['server_time']<threshold) & 
  (dataframe['server_time']>threshold7)]
  entries = len(UserData)
  Unique_Session_Count = UserData.session_id.nunique()
  return entries,Unique_Session_Count

for id in Train.index:
  print (id)    
  user_id = (Train.loc[[id],['user_id']].values[0])[0]
  threshold = (Train.loc[[id],['impression_time']].values[0])[0]
  threshold7 = (Train.loc[[id],['AdThreshold_date']].values[0])[0]
  dataframe=[]
  Train.loc[[id],'LogEntries_7days'],Train.loc[[id],'Sessioncounts_7days'] = 
  ServerLogData(user_id,threshold,threshold7,dataframe)
```

This approach is incredibly slow and just like in databases, can we use apply method here or something else which could be fast enough.

Please suggest me a better approach

Edit: Based on suggestions from super-helpful colleagues here, I am putting some data images for both dataframes and some explanation.
In dataframe Train, there will be user actions with some date values and there will be multiple rows for a user_id.
For each row, I pass user_id and dates to another dataframe and calculate some values. Please note that the second dataframe too has multiple rows for user_id for different dates. So grouping them does not seem be an option here. 
I pass user_id and dates, flow goes to second dataframe and find rows based on user_id which fits the dates too that I passed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you fix the indentation ?

Comment: There are multiple rows in `Train` with the same `id`?

Comment: @Acccumulation - Yes.....multiple rows in Train too. Each row has user_id and a date and those are passed to other dataframe to find out some values.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a groupby user_id then you pass each user's history as a dataframe, I think it will get you faster results than passing your Train line by line. I have used this method on log files data and it wasn't slow I don't know if it is the optimal solution but I found the results satisfying and quite easy to implement. Something like this:

```
group_user = LogItem.groupby('user_id')
group_train = Train.groupby('user_id')
user_ids = Train['user_id'].unique().tolist()
for x in user_ids:
    df_user = group_user.get_group(x)
    df_train = group_train.get_group(x)
    # do your thing here
    processing_function(df_user, df_train)
```

Write a function doing the calculation you want (I named it processing_function). I hope it helps.

EDIT: here is how your code becomes

```
def ServerLogData(threshold, threshold7, df_user):
    UserData = df_user[(df_user['server_time'] < threshold) & (df_user['server_time'] > threshold7)]
    entries = len(UserData)
    Unique_Session_Count = UserData.session_id.nunique()
    return entries, Unique_Session_Count


group_user = LogItem.groupby('user_id')
group_train = Train.groupby('user_id')
user_ids = Train['user_id'].unique().tolist()
for x in user_ids:
    df_user = group_user.get_group(x)
    df_train = group_train.get_group(x)
    for id in df_train.index:
        user_id = (df_train.loc[[id], ['user_id']].values[0])[0]
        threshold = (df_train.loc[[id], ['impression_time']].values[0])[0]
        threshold7 = (df_train.loc[[id], ['AdThreshold_date']].values[0])[0]
        df_train.loc[[id], 'LogEntries_7days'], df_train.loc[[id], 'Sessioncounts_7days'] = ServerLogData(threshold, threshold7, df_user)
```

Comment: @Souha-Thanks for your help here . Please see data and my edits in the question.

Comment: @ChandanJha "Please note that the second dataframe too has multiple rows for user_id for different dates. So grouping them does not seem be an option here." I don't see why you think that is not an option. If the user_id is unique and is the same for each user, the groupby function returns a dataframe of that specific user_id including all his usage history and all the different dates: it just runs through the whole dataframe and returns rows with that specific user_id.

Comment: @Souha- Let me try it out and will let you know in sometime. Thanks for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: @Souha- I get sense what you are trying to recommend by group by. this way the second dataframe where I am actually updating some columns for a user id, your approach will make us touch a particular user_id only once. However, not able to implement it well.

Comment: @Souha- I get sense what you are trying to recommend by group by. owever, not able to implement it well.
Example:
group user

user_id  server_time  session_id

1           2018-01-01   435
2           2018-01-02   564
1           2018-01-04   675
1           2018-01-05   454
1           2018-01-06   920 
group_train 

user_id  impression_time  count 
1         2018-01-03      0
1         2018-01-05      0

Logic: impression_time>server_time
Expected output for group_train is:
user_id  impression_time  count 
1         2018-01-03      2
1         2018-01-05      3

Comment: @ChandanJha I don't understand your last comment, but if you follow my method the way I have specified in my code block above you should replace `for id in Train.index: ` by `for id in df_train.index: ` and in your function ServerLogData pass as a parameter df_user (delete the parameter dataframe because it is the definition of df_user) and instead of passing user_id pass x (because it is the user id of that dataframe you passed) that will do I guess

Comment: the user_id parameter becomes useless delete it and here `UserData = dataframe.loc[(dataframe['user_id']==user_id) & 
  (dataframe['server_time']<threshold) & 
  (dataframe['server_time']>threshold7)]` just becomes `UserData =(df_user['server_time']<threshold) &  (df_user['server_time']>threshold7)]`

Comment: That way your code becomes more readable because the logic is more obvious, about rapidity you have to test it

Comment: @ChandanJha I edited my response and added the transformed code, please check the logic perhaps I might made some mistakes as I don't totally understand your use case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198675/discussion-between-souha-and-chandanjha).

Comment: Thank you so much @Souha for being so patient. I joined the chatroom.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a really large dataframe, printing each row is going to eat up a lot of time, and it's not like you'll be able to read throw thousands of lines of output anyway.

If you have a lot of rows for each `id`, then you can speed it up quite a bit by processing each `id` only once. There's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035764/remove-rows-with-duplicate-indices-pandas-dataframe-and-timeseries) that discsusses filtering a dataframe to unique indices. The top rated answer, adjusted for this case, would be `unique_id_df = Train.loc[~Train.index.duplicated(keep='first')]`. That creates a dataframe with only one row for each `id`. It takes the first row for each `id`, which seems to be what you're doing as well.

You can then create a dataframe from applying your function to  `unique_id_df`. There are several ways to do this. One is to create a series `entries_counts_series = unique_id_df.apply(ServerLogData,axis=1)` and then turn it into a dataframe with `entries_counts_df = pd.DataFrame(entries_counts_series.tolist(), index = entries_counts_series.index)`. You could also put the data into `unique_id_df` with `unique_id_df['LogEntries_7days'],unique_id_df['Sessioncounts_7days'] = zip(*unique_id_df.apply(ServerLogData,axis=1)`, but then you would have a bunch of extra columns to get rid of.

Once you have your data, you can merge it with your original dataframe: `Train_with_data = Train.merge(entries_counts_df, left_index = True, right_index = True)`. If you put the data into `unique_id_df`, you could do something such as `Train_with_data = Train.merge(unique_id_df[['LogEntries_7days','Sessioncounts_7days']], left_index = True, right_index = True)`.

Try out different variants of this and the other answers, and see how long each of them take on a subset of your data.

Also, some notes on `ServerLogData`:

1. `dataframe` is passed as a parameter, but then immediately overwritten.
2. You subset `LogItem` to where `LogItem['user_id']==user_id`, but then you check that condition again. Unless I'm missing something, you can get rid of the `dataframe = LogItem[LogItem['user_id']==user_id]` line.
3. You've split the line that sets `UserData` up, which is good, but standard style is to indent the lines in this sort of situation.
4. You're only using `session_id`, so you only need to take that part of the dataframe.

So:

```
def ServerLogData(user_id,threshold,threshold7):
    UserData = LogItem.session_id.loc[(LogItem['user_id']==user_id) & 
                             (LogItem['server_time']<threshold) & 
                             (LogItem['server_time']>threshold7)]
    entries = len(UserData)
    Unique_Session_Count = UserData.nunique()
    return entries, Unique_Session_Count
```

I did some quite-possibly-not-representative tests, and subsetting column, rather than subsetting the entire dataframe and then taking the column out from that dataframe, sped things up significantly.

Comment: @Accumulation- Thanks a lot for putting efforts to help me here. I did try your suggestion but it did not cut down the processing time by a big margin. I added my data images and added some comments at the end again. Kindly take a look.