# Using rolling with datetime index and duplicate timestamps

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe `df` that goes like this

```
index     data
midnight  1
1am       1
2am       1
2am       1
```

I want to count the number of lines in the last 90 minutes excl, to do so, I do
`df.rolling("90min", closed="left").fillna(0)`

Result is

```
index     data
midnight  0
1am       1
2am       1
2am       2
```

Considering `2am` is a duplicate index, I would like the last value to be `1` instead of `2`. Any idea ?

Comment: so how you are performing rolling on the string data?

Comment: try [removing duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13035764/remove-pandas-rows-with-duplicate-indices) first and then roll

Comment: @woblob I don't want to remove duplicate. each line is associated with an id and I want the rolling count at every given moment to be linked with the id

Comment: @AnuragDabas I'm performing rolling on the data field, which is numeric